# connect tables and write SQL query to retrieve data

Tags: oracle

I have the following tables

```
customer
custID | name | address
```

And

```
magazinesubscription
customerID | magazinename | cost | startdate | enddate

newspapersubscription
customerID | newspapername | cost | startdate | enddate

newspaper
newspapername | cost | publishedby

magazine
magazinename | cost | publishedby
```

Now what I want to is to print for each customer, their name, address, their magazine subscription, their newspaper subscriptions which include the name and publisher of the magazine and newspaper and the end date for each of this subscription.

I have tried doing this, but it does not work.

```
select * from customer
JOIN
(select  customerID, newspapername, enddate, n.publishedby 
 from newspapersubscription ns and newspaper n 
 where published in(select publishedby 
                    from newspaper 
                    where ns.newspapername = n.newspapername)
UNION
select  customerID, magazinename, enddate, m.publishedby 
from magazinesubscription ms and magazine m 
 where published in(select publishedby 
                    from magazine 
                     where ms.newspapername = m.newspapername));
```

Comment: Why do you think AND is valid joining syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with the above query. But I can point the error in the query you wrote.

`and` is not a valid sql keyword to take data from different tables.

```
(select  customerID, newspapername, enddate, n.publishedby 
 from newspapersubscription ns, newspaper n 
 where published in(select publishedby 
                    from newspaper 
                    where ns.newspapername = n.newspapername)
UNION
select  customerID, magazinename, enddate, m.publishedby 
from magazinesubscription ms, magazine m 
 where published in(select publishedby 
                    from magazine 
                     where ms.newspapername = m.newspapername));
```

After you get the result of the above query. You are joining with customer table without having any condition. This will behave as a cartesian product of two tables resulting in combining all data.